# Spam in comment section on Google Play - what is more powerfull vote down or flag as spam?

Tags: google-play-store, spam

I am a developer who develops one of the main digital version of newspaper in my country. 
 Many (not most) tend to write what they think about politics instead posting valuable comments. I would like to clean this mess on my app's Google Play page.

What would be more appropriate action as a developer - flagging comments as spam or just clicking vote down? What is Your experience?

[image]

In comment:

> This newspapers is b** sh**. This newspaper turn your brain into sh**. Do not read this newspaper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that as a general principle, spam and posts with offensive abuse should always be flagged.

Flagging brings them to the attention of someone who may be able to delete the post and the account of the poster.

Downvoting leaves the possibility that the posts remain visible.  It may take a while for a flag to be acted upon but - no flag - no action.